# How to handle optional fields for this model?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on a small database that has information for staff, teachers and students. Because I am only storing information like `name`, `lastname`, `gender`, `id` and their `role` on the sistem I decided to use a `Person` table with this fields.

But here is where I am having trouble, the student can have information like `allergies`, `blood type` etc. Such information is only applied to the `Student` role so I am clearly reluctant in making those columns in `Person`

I am also not sure if having a table `Medical_Record` would be an appropiate solution. I was hoping someone could give me some pointers to solve this problem.

Here is my preliminary design:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making another table is suitable for this situation, although you may want to include the users(student) id as a column within the `MedicalRecord` table. Then creating a relation between the users id in `MedicalRecord` to `Person`, this then helps with the time to process a query to fetch a row of the data inside `MedicalRecord` with the users id.